# Beta Testing using Google

Tags: android, beta-testing

I've searched for answers to these two questions but have found nothing specifically.

1. I have my app in the Google Play Store Alpha / Beta testing area with no problems. Once I publish the app to the public, am I still able to upload different versions of the APK to the Alpha/Beta testing sections?
2. In the app store, you see apps available with the name XXX(Beta). Has something special been done here or have they just published the app with "Beta" as part of the name. If this is the case, then is my assumption correct that I can change the name of my app in the playstore as long as I don't change the package name.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. I have my app in the Google Play Store Alpha / Beta testing area with no problems. Once I publish the app to the public, am I still able to upload different versions of the APK to the Alpha/Beta testing sections?

Yes.

> 2. In the app store, you see apps available with the name XXX(Beta). Has something special been done here or have they just published the app with "Beta" as part of the name. If this is the case, then is my assumption correct that I can change the name of my app in the playstore as long as I don't change the package name.

This is just part of the app name on Google Play. The app name is independent from the package name and can be changed.